# Issues generating Push Notification SSL Certificate

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to generate an Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificate - here's a screen-grab: 
[image: generating screen]
<sub>(source: [818kimball.com](http://www.818kimball.com/Images/Generating.gif))</sub>

(blurred certificate name for privacy purposes) 

but after hanging at that screen for 2 minutes, I then keep getting this error:

[image: generating screen]
<sub>(source: [818kimball.com](http://www.818kimball.com/Images/error.png))</sub>

I'm doing everything right, I checked and re-did all my steps, several times, verified it all using multiple sources (like http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) - but this error keeps popping up.

Anyone have any idea what's going on or how to solve it?
And in the error, where it says "or try using the Provisioning Portal" - anyone know what specifically they're talking about? I mean I know where the provisioning profile is, I poked around in there - but what specifically am I supposed to click or do there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have happened to me sometime. I think i got it solved by using another apple id(since my company had another one). But that may not be necessary. Try doing it after sometime, clearing all your browser cache. It should work, if what you are doing is correct

Comment: which one worked? trying with new apple id, or repeating after sometime?